# How does Armour work in Savage Worlds?

Tags: savage-worlds

I am a bit confused about how Armour and Armour Piercing is meant to work.

If you have a Toughness of 8 and Armour of say +2 (10) and you are hit by a weapon with AP 2. Do you take 2 off for the AP so it is back to 8 first. Or does the damage need to be more than 10 and then you take the 2 off to determine the result?

Comment: Both answers are correct but I can only bless one not both. As the choice is arbitrary and as Karick has the lest rep, I choose him. Thanks Toast for you answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How AP damage works is detailed briefly on page 48 of *Savage Worlds Deluxe Edition*, in the introduction of the Gear chapter:

> The weapon or round ignores this many points of Armor. […] Excess AP is simply lost.

The AP2 means that in this instance the effective Toughness is 8. If it was AP4 it would ignore up to 4 points of armor, but in this case there are only 2 points of armor, so AP4 in this instance would *also* mean that the effective Toughness is 8.

The other way you thought it might work wouldn't model armor piercing, but something more like a "hollowpoint" round that does an especially high amount of damage *if* it gets through armor, but isn't any better at getting through armor than a normal bullet.

Answer (score 13):

> If you have a Toughness of 8 and Armour of say +2 (10) and you are hit
> by a weapon with AP 2.

AP 2 means the weapon ignores 2 points of armor.  In this case, your effective armor is 8 and 8 damage will result in your character being shaken.

If the weapon had AP 4, your effective toughness would still be 8 because it can only ignore as much armor as you actually have.

This assumes we're talking about regular armor.  If you're using a setting with heavy weapons and heavy armor (ex: Necessary Evil), remember that only heavy weapons can do any damage to heavy armor.

Here's a [forum link describing armor for NPCs](http://archive.pegforum.com/viewtopic.php?t=36410).

Comment: Well it is 7 years old.  Thankfully Pinacle kept the old forums archived:  http://archive.pegforum.com/viewtopic.php?t=36410

Comment: Cool, thanks for the Edit.